# Laravel 5.5 trying to use Aws SES to send mails but it keeps returning errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, amazon-ses

I am setting up a website with a contact form that will use AWS SES to send mail. I have set up my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_HOST=us-west-2
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=AKADADQADADGX45EO
MAIL_PASSWORD=EASDDEWWWEDWEDASDQWDQWDBTb5
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My mail.php is set up to use the .env() vaules
same with services.php:

```
'ses' => [
        'key' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'secret' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'region' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
    ],
```

I have applied for and been removed from sandbox.

I have the IAM user set up with AmazonSESFullAccess and even made my own policy (AmazonSesSendingAccess) just in case the above was not right:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this keeps coming up:

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted i ▶
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">\n
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>MessageReje (truncated...)\n
 MessageRejected (client): Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: email@email.com - <ErrorResponse  ▶
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>\n
    <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: email@email.com</Message>\n
  </Error>\n
  <RequestId>269f02b9-1320-4882-b3d4-0cd57559aaea</RequestId>\n
</ErrorResponse>
```

I am at a loss on this. I shouldn't need to verify anything since I am not in sandbox anymore. One last thing I have made certain that I was approved for US West Oregon which is us-west-2.

Comment: don't ever post credentials here...

Comment: You have to verify your domain and email from the AWS control panel itself, try to look at the points 2 and 3 in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@martin.riedweg/configure-amazon-ses-on-laravel-5-8-in-5-minutes-764c30df6399)

Comment: Hi jtwes, those are fake. I had no weird characters in my actual ones so I just put a string of random characters in to keep the look.

Comment: @mdexp with being in production I thought that eliminated the need to verify the domain name? The way the email is set up is someone fills out the form, puts in their email and the email goes to the site owner from the from:form filler emails email so they can just respond. Theres no way to verify potentially thousands of emails especially since I won't know them before hand. In the past I could do this without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to verify your domain and email from the AWS control panel itself, try to look at the points 2 and 3 in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@martin.riedweg/configure-amazon-ses-on-laravel-5-8-in-5-minutes-764c30df6399).

To answer to your comment:
I'm not saying that you would have to verify your client emails, as that's impossible, maybe just create a `no-reply@yourdomain.com` or similar, that will be the email sender, and set the email's reply-to header to the email the customer put in the form.

That domain verification has to be done because AWS have to be sure you do own the domain of the email account that is sending the email.

That's a spam prevention measure, otherwise you could just fake the mail sender in the email header itself and maybe the AWS mail server might get flagged for spam (that would affect also other users that is using AWS to send emails).

Comment: Thanks for this. It sent me down the right path. I looked into the verifying domains piece and read this article, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console. By verifying the domain and going with your suggestion of no-reply@ this handles the problem, I just need to send the email to the client and they will have to reply back in their own email account manually. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't verified the domain (or email) that you want to send from in SES.

You should verify the domain, following the instructions on AWS's site (adding required DNS records, etc). See the following page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

If you are planning on only sending from a single email, you can manually verify it in the SES dashboard.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html

Comment: The problem is I want to send from hundreds of different ones. And I don't know which ones until the user fills out the form. Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: You should not send from domains you don't control.

Comment: If you want people to be able to reply to the emails, send them from an email you control (eg: no-reply@domain.com) and set the reply-to so the replies go to the correct address